# How to stop a function from running on encountering a condition on python?

Tags: python, break, odeint

I'm trying to solve/simulate a material balance equation in Python. I want to stop the simulation when one of the concentration values goes negative. I've used a conditional statement followed by break function. There is no error displayed. I'm not understanding as to why that is not working. Is the placement of break statement right? Please help!!
Here is my code:

```
def simulation(z,t,k):

    k1 = k[0]
    k2 = k[1]
    k3 = k[2]
    tol = z[0] 
    H = z[1]
    O = z[2] 


    dHdt = k1*tol*H - k2*tol*H
    dtoldt = (-k1 * tol * H) - (k1 * tol * H) - (k3 * tol * O)
    dOdt = -k3*tol*O

    for i in range (0,3):
        if z[i] < 0:
           break

   return [dHdt, dtoldt, dOdt]

k = [125.656, 478.36, 2698.3]
t = np.linspace(0, 1000, 100)
z0 = [100, 150, 200]

z = odeint(simulation, z0, t, args=(k,))
print(z)
```

Comment: replace the `break` with `return [dHdt, dtoldt, dOdt]` since currently you have only one `return` in the code.

Comment: `break` stops the execution of the current loop (`for`). But your `for` loop does not do enything, so there is no difference whether you break from it or not. If you want to exit from the whole function, use `return`.

Comment: the `for` loop isn't doing anything. Whether you `break` or `return` from it, you'll still get the same result. Should the `for` loop be changing values or rerunning the simulation? Perhaps the `for` loop should be outside of the function and call the function with varying inputs?

Comment: can you reproduce your problem with above code? 
Or could it be that an essential line is missing in above example?

Comment: Thank you. Suppose I want to calculate z only till the values obtained from z are positive, will it not be wrong to place the conditional statement outside the function? Because placing it outside the might only over write or print only the positive values. Please correct me.

Comment: You need to so something louder than returning if you want to abandon the `odeint`; have you considered exceptions?